# Find Gradient Magnitude using skimage.feature.hog module

Tags: python, image-processing, scikit-image, feature-extraction

I am trying to print total gradient magnitude for 100 in the below array

```
img=[[150,50,121],[12,100,25],[201,243,244]]
```

Below is the code I tried

```
from skimage.feature import hog
from skimage import data, exposure
fdt, hog_image = hog([[150,50,121],[12,100,25],[201,243,244]], orientations=2, pixels_per_cell=(1, 1), cells_per_block=(1, 1), visualize=True)
print(hog_image)
```

The value I get is 43. But Now when I calculate manually I am getting the value as 193.437 . formulae for manual calculation is as below

```
import math
math.sqrt((25-12)**2+(243-50)**2)
```

both results do not match up. Any suggestion on what I am doing wrong. I am running on python version 3

Comment: Have you read [the documentation](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/auto_examples/features_detection/plot_hog.html)? Because you are confused that two totally different computations yield different results…

Comment: The HOG feature extractor is doing more than just taking the difference and calculating the euclidean norm.  It also is performing global image normalization and block normalization as well as computing the histograms that form the basis of the features.